# How to calculate time taken by individual thread to execute the request in Jmeter?

Tags: multithreading, time, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, group

if I am having 10 threads running to execute 5 http requests, and at the end of execution I want to know time take by each thread to execute those 5 http request , how can I do that ? can someone please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put these 5 HTTP Requests under the [Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller/)

You might also want to add [__threadNum() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) to the Transaction Controller's label in order to be able to distinguish the aggregate response times for individual threads

[image]

[image]